# Creating a Scheme list from a box and pointer

Tags: scheme, computer-science

For anyone who knows Scheme: how would you make a list using this box and pointer image?
[image]

I've tried a lot of different things, but I don't think I really understand scheme.

Comment: With 3 `list`s or a bunch of  `cons`es.

Comment: Hints: every horizontal row of "boxes" (cons cells in scheme) is a list. Lists can have lists as elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box and pointer image is simply the visual equivalent of

(cons (cons 1 '())
(cons 2
(cons (cons 3 (cons 4 '()))
(cons 5 '()))))

Knowing that a list is a succession of conses ending in the empty list, e.g.,
(list 1 2 3) would return the same as
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))
namely the list '(1 2 3)

the structure in the box and pointer diagram can also be seen (and created) as a list of lists:

(list (list 1)
2
(list 3 4)
5)

Comment: Wow, seeing this answer actually really helps visualize it better. Thank you!